# Scene Builder preview is different than Actual output

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix, gluon-desktop

I am getting Scene Builder Preview as following 
 [image]

 but when I run my project It's displaying different as following 
 [image]

**Application:-** JavaFX using Jfoenix and GluonDesktop
**Designing using:-** Scene Builder 
**Development IDE:-** intelliJ 
**OS:-** MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

Is this expected behavior? Do I need to do some config to display the same in all platforms. As I am very new to JavaFX. Looking for help.

Comment: It looks as if the JFoenix CSS files have not been applied to your project. Did you initialize the project correctly? I cannot be more specific because I know only very little about JFoenix.

Comment: @mipa I have not referenced any CSS in scene builder as well as intelliJ.

Comment: Do I need to have any default CSS of JFoenix applied in my project even I have not used any CSS in my implementation? I am also new in JFoenix, JavaFX and GluonDesktop. :)

Comment: JFoenix uses CSS internally (like JavaFX itself too) and that seems to missing. I also wonder whether JFoenix can be used together with GluonDesktop which also seems to fiddle arround with the default CSS.

Comment: Oh is it. Let me look into this more deep. (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a Theme selected by [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) which was displaying effects/components of current selected UI Theme (Mine was [Gluon Mobile Light theme](https://gluonhq.com/comments-app-getting-started-with-gluon-charm/)). As I said I was very new to this I didn't have much knowledge about it.

Thank you.